# Estimating memory footprint of a C program (and programs in a scripting language using bindings to a C library)

Tags: memory-management, software-engineering

I wanted to test the feasibility of an idea that might be part of a small project, and I'm trying to set up a quick prototype using Python (with bindings to a C library). If any of this is sufficient for any interesting application, I might make this the main topic of my thesis.

I was able to plot how much memory this prototype uses (sort of experimentally) using psutils and randomly generated problem instances, but I would like to know if there's a more principled/enigineer-like approach to memory profiling (I want to start learning about these topics, because I would like to make reliable estimates in order to better plan ahead).

I'm looking for literature suggestions and practical advice.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems more appropriate for [so].

Comment: I thought stackoverflow was aimed towards specific issues with specific code! I'll try :)